# Double field module theming

Tags: 8, theming

Could anyone please help with the Double field module in Drupal 8 and Twig? I am trying to produce the following with no luck so far as I cannot figure out the proper Twig variables to use.

```
<li><dl class="classname"><dt>{{ first }}</dt><dd>{{ second }}</dd></dl></li>
```

I would like to have the raw values in the html above.
-- I'm adding some more info here because my goal is to understand the mechanics of twig in this case and how I can get the field values of the two subitems

I have overriden (as suggested by drupal's theme debug system) the field--fieldname.html.twig template in which I have the following

```
<ul class="list-sm">
{% for item in items %}
<li>
  <dl class="list-terms-inline">
    <dt>
      {{ item.first }}
    </dt>
    <dd>
      {{ item.second }}
    </dd>
  </dl>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

which is not printing anything in the value areas and apart from that does not iterate through all the items either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using default (Unformatted list) formatter override *double-field-item.html.twig* template with the following markup:

```
<dt>{{ item.first }}</dt><dd>{{ item.second }}</dd>
```

Note that Double field ships with HTML list formatter which may render definition list so you might not need to override anything.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @ya.teck, but I still cannot quite grasp the solution. I am not very proficient with drupal excuse my possible ignorance, but are you suggesting I override the double-field-item.html.twig in general? Can I do that by just adding a file with the same name in my theme's templates folder? I have actually already used the {{ item.first/second }} markup on the drupal suggested field template iterating through items but I get no output at all.

Comment: You need to clear caches for the changes to take effect. Also consider using the second approach with HTML list formatter. Seems it covers your case perfectly.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion @ya.teck I had a look at the definition list provided and in fact it is working but I'm having a little inconsistency with what the actual html of my theme is so I would really like to understand why isn't the code I added to my original question not working, as it is important all customisations are kept within the actual theme's files and not base anything on core or module alterations.

Comment: The code you used in `field--fieldname.html.twig` is wrong. You should not use `item.first` and `item.second` there.

Comment: "a little inconsistency with what the actual html of my theme is"
Note the you can override a template (`double-field-definition-list.html.twig`) for the definition list as well.